# Настройка smtp Yandex в Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby, smtp, яндекс-почта

Для реализации отправки сообщений из приложения было опробовано два пути: первый - компактный, и хоть не без проблем, но отправка сообщения происходит.

Второй (следуя [руководству по ActionMailer](http://rusrails.ru/action-mailer-basics)) - не такой компактный и сообщения не отправляются.

Хочу разобраться с обоими

### Вариант 1

```
#app/controllers/feedback_info_controller.rb

def send_mail
 smtp = Net::SMTP.new( "smtp.yandex.ru", 587 )
 smtp.enable_starttls
 smtp.start( "yandex.ru", "my_adr@yandex.ru", "пароль", :plain ) do |conn|
 conn.send_message "Сообщение", "my_adr@yandex.ru", "получатель@rambler.ru"
end
```

В этом случае, на почту получатель@rambler.ru приходит письмо (без темы) от MAILER-DAEMON@ со следующим содержанием:

> by mail172.rambler.ru (rmaild SMTP 1.2.41)

> with ESMTP id 292593804 for получатель@rambler.ru; Mon, 24 Aug 2015 11:13:46 +0300

> Received: from forward22m.cmail.yandex.net (forward22m.cmail.yandex.net [5.255.216.16])

> ```
>     by mx2.mail.rambler.ru (Postfix) with ESMTP id 65FF15CA8
>     for <получатель@rambler.ru>; Mon, 24 Aug 2015 11:13:46 +0300 (MSK)
> ```

Received: from smtp3m.mail.yandex.net (smtp3m.mail.yandex.net [IPv6:2a02:6b8:0:2519::125])

> ```
>     by forward22m.cmail.yandex.net (Yandex) with ESMTP id 488F18046B
>     for <получатель@rambler.ru>; Mon, 24 Aug 2015 11:13:46 +0300 (MSK)
> ```
>
> Received: from smtp3m.mail.yandex.net (localhost [127.0.0.1])

> ```
>     by smtp3m.mail.yandex.net (Yandex) with ESMTP id 2C1A127A05B8
>     for <получатель@rambler.ru>; Mon, 24 Aug 2015 11:13:46 +0300 (MSK)
> ```
>
> Received: by smtp3m.mail.yandex.net (nwsmtp/Yandex) with ESMTPSA id lnLUHk87ag-DjpWkB95;

> Mon, 24 Aug 2015 11:13:45 +0300

> (using TLSv1 with cipher AES128-SHA (128/128 bits))

> (Client certificate not present)

> Message-Id: 20150824111345.DjpWkB95@smtp3m.mail.yandex.net

> Date: Mon, 24 Aug

> 2015 11:13:45 +0300

> From: MAILER-DAEMON

> To: undisclosed-recipients:;

> X-Spam: yes

### Вариант 2

Создание и использование рассыльщика FeedbackMailer

```
   #app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
    class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base 
    end

   #app/mailers/feedback_mailer.rb
    class FeedbackMailer < ApplicationMailer
    def feedback_email
      mail(from: 'my_adr@yandex.ru', to: 'получатель@rambler.ru', subject: 'тема')
    end
    end 

   #app/controllers/feedback_info_controller.rb
    def feedback_send
       FeedbackMailer.feedback_email
    end

  #config/environments/development.rb
    config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
        address: 'smtp.yandex.ru',
        port: 587,
        domain: 'yandex.ru',
        authentication: 'plain',
        user_name: 'my_adr@yandex.ru',
        password: 'пароль',
        enable_starttls_auto: true
    }
```

с такими настройками ничего не происходит

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
tls: true,
```

...

Без этого yandex не работает. Причем **tls:** в официальной документации нет.

Answer (score 3):

Работает с такими настройками:

```
#development.rb
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:tls => true,
address: 'smtp.yandex.ru',
port: 465,
domain: 'yandex.ru',
authentication: 'plain',
user_name: 'name@yandex.ru',
password: 'пароль'
}


#mailers/application_mailer.rb
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base 
end


#mailers/feedback_mailer.rb
class FeedbackMailer < ApplicationMailer

def feedback_email (name, phone, comment)
@name = name
@phone = phone
@comment = comment
mail(from: 'name@yandex.ru', to: 'adrr@example.com', subject: 'Тема письма')
end
end 


#controllers/feedback_info_controller.rb
def feedback_send

@name = CGI.escapeHTML(params[:feedback_info][:name])
@phone = CGI.escapeHTML(params[:feedback_info][:phone])
@comment = CGI.escapeHTML(params[:feedback_info][:comment])

FeedbackMailer.feedback_email(@name,@phone,@comment).deliver_now   
end
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Во втором варианте вы пропустили, собственно, доставку. Вы создали объект письма, но не запустили отправку. С Rails 4.2+ можно спокойно использовать `.deliver_later`:

```
FeedbackMailer.feedback_email.deliver_later
```

Но сначала перечитайте [руководство](http://rusrails.ru/action-mailer-basics), особенно этот абзац:

> Поведением Active Job по умолчанию является запуск заданий `:inline`. Поэтому можно использовать `deliver_later` для отсылки писем прямо сейчас, а если позже решите отправлять письма в фоновой задаче, вам нужно будет всего лишь настроить Active Job для использования бэкэнда очередей (Sidekiq, Resque и т.п.).

Comment: D-side, Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В Rails 5 для настройки в `config/environments/production.rb` добавил:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'www.yoursite.ru' }
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  tls: true,
  address: "smtp.yandex.com",
  port: 465,
  domain: "yandex.com",
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: 'youremail@yandex.ru',
  password: 'yourpassword'
}
```

Все отлично работает, в том числе с почтой для домена (pdd.yandex.ru). Однако в отличии от gmail, письмо не сохраняется в папке отправленные на сервере.