# настройка SMTP в gitlab omnibus

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails, gitlab, raspbian

Поднял на raspberry pi 2 gitlab omnibus на localhost, морда запустилась, но при регистрации требуется подтвердить аккаунт через email. Всё делалось по [документации](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/smtp.md) для Yandex почты.

```
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "smtp.yandex.ru"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 25
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "mymail@yandex.ru"
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "mypass"
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "yandex.ru"
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
#gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = false
gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'peer' # Can be: 'none', 'peer', 'client_once', 'fail_if_no_peer_cert', see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base...
#gitlab_rails['smtp_ca_path'] = "/etc/ssl/certs"
#gitlab_rails['smtp_ca_file'] = "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
```

Я использовал порыт: 25, 465, 587.

Comment: без лога попытки подключения можно разве что гадать на кофейной гуще. как получить этот лог — ищите в документации. либо gitlab-а, либо rails.

Comment: попытка угадать: [попробуйте `smtp_tls = true`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/444817/178576). ну и порт тогда 465-й — более подходит. и аутентификацию логичнее указывать в этом случае — `plain`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin я бы показал логи, но они все пустые

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Покопавшись некоторое время смог разобраться.
Первым делом в свойстве `external_url` в начале файла указываем домен на котором работает ваш gitlab, в моём случае т.к. хостится он в локальной сети будет выглядеть так `"http://192.168.0.105"`. По этому полю будет генерироваться URL который будет отправляться на почту.

Далее листаем ниже и раскомичиваем (убираем #) строки:

```
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "smtp.yandex.ru"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 465
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "вашаПочта@yandex.ru"
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "ВапПароль"
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "yandex.ru"
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "plain"
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'peer' # Can be: 'none', 'peer', 'client_once', 'fail_if_no_peer_cert', see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base...
gitlab_rails['smtp_ca_path'] = "/etc/ssl/certs"
gitlab_rails['smtp_ca_file'] = "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
```

Потом дописываем строки сами (их также найти и раскомитить):

```
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_reply_to'] = 'вашаПочта@yandex.ru'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = 'вашаПочта@yandex.ru'
```

Сохраняемся, выходим, запускаем `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

Чтобы протестировать запускаем `sudo gitlab-rails console`, после чего появится приглашение для ввода, туда вводим `Notify.test_email('почтаДляТеста@address.com', 'Message Subject', 'Message Body').deliver_now`. Если всё правильно сделали на почту должна придти сообщение.

Comment: к сожалению у меня не заработало(